# AWS IAM Global Condition Key aws:PrincipalOrgPaths throws an Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use the IAM Global Condition Key **aws:PrincipalOrgPaths** in an S3 bucket policy, but I keep getting an "Access denied" error. I am able to use the Key **aws:PrincipalOrgID** just fine. The sanitized bucket policy below is what I am trying to use.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "MyOrgOnly",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::thebucketofmydreams",
        "arn:aws:s3:::thebucketofmydreams/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": "o-funny/r-stuff/ou-path"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you trying to create a new policy

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter - I can change the word "PrincipalOrgID" and that works.

Comment: for my knowledge, can you tell me what you are trying to do, i never had to use `PrincipalOrgPaths`. are you trying to use active directory ?

Comment: I am attempting to restrict access to this bucket to only those inside my AWS Organization

Answer (score 7):

So, the final answer is that it was a syntax error. The PrincipalOrgPaths requires square brackets, even though it is a single entity. If you try this, you'll notice that once accepted, the square brackets will be stripped out of the final policy. Thanks, AWS!

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "MyOrgOnly",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::thebucketofmydreams",
        "arn:aws:s3:::thebucketofmydreams/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": ["o-funny/r-stuff/ou-path"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change PrincipleOrgPaths conditions from "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": "o-funny/r-stuff/ou-path/" to "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": "o-funny/r-stuff/ou-path/*" so all can access under the organization path. You are missing * here

Comment: The * in this case did not solve my issue. It is still a syntax error.